# Unexpected Method Call despite having mocking statement for FOR loop : EasyMock

Tags: java, tdd, dao, easymock, cucumber-junit

I having a hard time to resolve the Unexpected method call error issues using EasyMock, which makes a DAO call inside a for loop.

```
for ( Car obj : carList) {
    objModified=carHelper.addPrice(obj);
    carServiceDao.create(objModified);
}
```

Testing Scenarios :

```
carServiceDao = EasyMock.createMock(ICarDaoDao.class);

EasyMock.expect(carServiceDao.create(EasyMock.anyObject(Car.class))).andReturn(carList);
```

> Error Scenario:
>                           java.lang.AssertionError: 
>                           Unexpected method call carServiceDao.create(null):
>                           at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:44)
>                           at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:94)
>                           at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:97)
>                           at #############################.######Impl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b59c96b7.create()
>                           at ✽.When the car service runs(CarCalculations.feature:##)

Another Testing Scenario :

```
EasyMock.expect(carServiceDao.create(carList)).andReturn(carList);
```

> java.lang.AssertionError: Unexpected method call carServiceDao.create(Car[name:###,color:####,fuel:###]):
>                 at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:44)
>                 at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:94)
>                 at org.easymock.internal.ClassProxyFactory$MockMethodInterceptor.intercept(ClassProxyFactory.java:97)
>                at #############################.######Impl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b59c96b7.create()
>                at ✽.When the car service runs(CarCalculations.feature:##)

Comment: Update to this problem , i have fixed by mocking only the DAO calls inside the loop and the remaining other calls to call the real test method by injecting the service calls using reflection , the isolation doesnt overrides the dao objects hence the problem fixed , but couldnt able to trace what exactly went wrong .

Answer (score 1):

Can't help. I would need a full example. But the replay part is missing.

I think the problem is that `EasyMock.expect(carServiceDao.create(EasyMock.anyObject(Car.class))).andReturn(carList);` only records ONE call. And then the loop is doing many calls. So on the second call, it will give the error you are seeing.

Doing something like `EasyMock.expect(carServiceDao.create(EasyMock.anyObject(Car.class))).andStubReturn(carList);` should do the trick.